# How to pass props to a function and access it in a component using react and typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i want to pass props along with routercomponent props and access it in a component using react and typescript.

i have a MainComponent which has a ChildComponent. I want to pass props namely isOpen, showdialog and hidedialog props to the ChildComponent.

Below is the code,

```
function MainComponent() {
    render= () => {
        return(
            <Route
                exact
                path="/items"
                render={routeProps => (
                    <Layout>
                        <ChildComponent
                            isOpen={isOpen}// how to access this
                            showDialog={showDialog} //how to access this
                            hideDialog={hideDialog} //how to access this
                            {...routeProps}
                        />
                    <Layout>
                )}
            />
        )
    }
}

function ChildComponent({ history }: RouteComponentProps) {
    //some logic
}
```

I have tried accessing like below

```
interface Props {
    isOpen: boolean;
    showDialog: any;
    hideDialog: any;
}

function ChildComponent({ history }: RouteComponentProps) { 
    //how to access it here...
}
```

I am not knowing how to access it here. could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the props interface to be a combination of RouteComponentProps and ChildProps. Post that destructure them from props

```
interface Props {
    isOpen: boolean;
    showDialog: any;
    hideDialog: any;
}

function ChildComponent({ history, isOpen, showDialog, hideDialog }: Props & RouteComponentProps<{}>) { 

}
```

P.S on a sidenote , a functional component doesn't have a render function so you just needed to write your MainComponent like

```
function MainComponent() {
    return(
        <Route
            exact
            path="/items"
            render={routeProps => (
                <Layout>
                    <ChildComponent
                        isOpen={isOpen}
                        showDialog={showDialog}
                        hideDialog={hideDialog}
                        {...routeProps}
                    />
                <Layout>
            )}
        />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just continuing destructuring it. Just make sure your types are lined up.

```js
function ChildComponent({ history, isOpen, showDialog, hideDialog }: RouteComponentProps) { 
    //how to access it here...
}
```

Remember that object you're passing into the function is an instance of React Props, so everything that is a property on the JSX is passed in the props object under the same keys.